# No results not working

Tags: channel-entries, channel, search, no-results, freebie

I'm trying to display one entry with the search:field_name parameter of ExpressionEngine. This works fine, but I can't get the no results tag to work. I have tried a lot of things, including the use of other things then exp:channel:entries. This is my current code:

```
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="projecten"
            dynamic="no"
            search:project_trackcode="={freebie_2}"
            limit="1"
            require_entry="yes"
        }
            test
            {if no_results}
               Geen resultaten
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

It doesn't matter if I set require entry to yes or no. The code does return entries if available, but when it doesn't find an entry, it doesn't even seem to enter the {exp:channel:entries}.

Comment: Why are you setting a limit on a tag you are using to display search results? If you need a search, I'm betting the {exp:search:simple_form} and {exp:search:search_results} tags will be your friend.

Comment: I don't see how that question is relevant to this. It doesn't matter what I use, no_results doesn't work either way.

Comment: No offense, but have you ever dug into the EE core? The {exp:search} tags could likely use different class and methods for searching, and you may be running into a bug. Also, questioning your parameter set up on that tag is very relevant to trying to help you :)

Comment: I'm not actually searching. I'm just displaying a result based on a variable in the URL, which is why I'm using freebie. This should only be one result and that's why I limit it to 1. The limitation should however not be necessary since the trackcode that I'm using in the url is unique.

Comment: However you did give me an idea which I'm going to try. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here but my guess is because you have dynamic="no" so it will always return a result.